# how to create an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know how to build an array I don't understand it, I already have the responses from the server in json_encode but I don't know how to use the results in an "input option".

```
     $nun=0;
     $arch = [];
     //$file='file.fsc';
     //echo dirname(__FILE__) . './../bankreceipts/*';
     foreach (glob(dirname(__FILE__) . './../bankreceipts/*') as $filename) {
         $nun++;
         $filename = basename($filename);
         $arch[$nun] = $filename;
     }
     echo json_encode($file);
```

the response from the server is:

```
{"1":"billy.pdf","2":"mov19-03-20222202319817.csv","3":"pichincha_15_03_2022.csv"}
```

I need the option to have value="billy.pdf" another value="mov19-03-20222202319817.csv" etc.

Comment: The opposite (or reverse) of `encode` is `decode` (just like the opposite (or reverse) of `encrypt` is `decrypt`)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why not add whateer you need to `$arch`?

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the response as an array using [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with the array argument as true, then treat it like key/values:

```
<?php

$data = '{"1":"billy.pdf","2":"mov19-03-20222202319817.csv","3":"pichincha_15_03_2022.csv"}';
$data = json_decode($data, true);
echo 'pdf: ' . $data["1"] . "\n";
echo 'csv 1: ' . $data["2"] . "\n";
echo 'csv 2: ' . $data["3"] . "\n";

/* output

pdf: billy.pdf
csv 1: mov19-03-20222202319817.csv
csv 2: pichincha_15_03_2022.csv

*/
```

https://tehplayground.com/9wbYaIulzsHmokqX